# An Extremely Strange Javascript Behavior: onLoad and $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, onload-event

I was building an auto check username availability function for an input field and I came across this extremely weird thing.

When I made the auto check function as a `$(document).ready()` function,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //JohnyP keydowntimer
    var timer = null;
    $('#username').keydown(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        var usercheck = $(this).val();
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
    checkUserName(usercheck);}, 1000);
    });
    //http://www.itechroom.com
    function checkUserName(usercheck){
            $('#usercheck').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post("checkuser.php", {username: usercheck} , function(data){
                if (data != '' || data != undefined || data != null){
                    $('#usercheck').html(data);
                }
            });
    }
})
```

No matter where I placed it (either before `</head>` or after `<body>`),
it couldn't work.

However, when I executed the function as a Body onload event (`<body onLoad="loadthis()">`)

```
function loadthis(){
    //JohnyP keydowntimer
    var timer = null;
    $('#username').keydown(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        var usercheck = $(this).val();
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
    checkUserName(usercheck);}, 1000);
    });
    //http://www.itechroom.com
    function checkUserName(usercheck){
            $('#usercheck').html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post("checkuser.php", {username: usercheck} , function(data){
                if (data != '' || data != undefined || data != null){
                    $('#usercheck').html(data);
                }
            });
    }
    }
```

It worked but every time it auto checked, the previous result appeared.

*eg. Typing in the name 'Arch', the message is supposed to be "this username already exists" but instead it is "this username is available" and the next result will be "this username already exists" regardless of anything. It is always the previous result.*

So I tried executing the check_user_name function as an `onblur` event and everything worked fine, there is nothing wrong in checkuser.php.

Can anyone explain to me why this is occurring? I'm new to jQuery.. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Dunno why `$(document).ready()` isn't working, but you got previous value because the `keydown` event is triggered **before** the character is being added to the textbox. You should handle `keyup` event instead. [Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/wT4th/).

Comment: Are there any errors? How about a jsFiddle example?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Oh thank you so much!!! Never think of that.. Both `$(document).ready()` and `onLoad` work perfectly now.. `$(document).ready()` wasn't working just now was due to a syntax error from the js above it.. Didn't notice it while I was testing the code. My bad.

Comment: @j08691 Nah.. Problem solved.

Comment: Cheers - so did the `keyup` instead of `keydown` solved your real problem?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Yeah. `keyup` ensured the event to be triggered after the user finished typing. Thanks again for helping me that. You've inspired me to think things from a different perspective while debugging:)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard ..So you want to put down your solution in a form of an answer instead of a comment? It would look odd to have the problem solved yet this is considered as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get  the previous value because the `keydown` event is triggered **before** the character is actually being added to the textbox.

You should handle the `keyup` event instead, which is raised after the value is updated:

```
$('#username').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var usercheck = $(this).val();
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        checkUserName(usercheck);
    }, 1000);
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/wT4th/).

As for the `$(document).ready()` not working, probably some syntax error causing the whole code between the `<script>` and `</script>` tags to fail.